# Which destructor is called when in C++?

Tags: c++, destructor

I am hunting memory leaks in a program.

I narrowed it down to some destructors not being called. However, I can't figure out why:

```
class CMain : public CList {
public:
    CMain();
    virtual ~CMain();
    ...
}

class CList : public CProc {
public:
    CList();
    virtual ~CList();
    ...
}

/* some code and a main func here */
CMain *pMain = new CMain();
/* some more code here */
delete pMain;
```

`CMain` gets deallocated just fine, but `~CList()` is never called. All parent classes of `CList` have virtual destructors, too.

Do you have any hints about why the destructor for `CList` is never called?

Comment: When you say `CMain gets deallocated just fine`, do you mean that `CMain::~CMain` is executed but `CList::~CList` is not? If so, how do you destroy the objects - using `delete o;`?

Comment: How do you know that specific destructor is not called?

Comment: @sharptooth: I put a breakpoint and some console outputs in the destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you set a breakpoint in ~CMain to see where it goes?

Comment: Doh. I only ever went a few steps into ~CMain. But you are correct. It never reaches the end of ~CMain.

Comment: Congrats. Then will some more debugging, you may eventually find why it's not called. PS: checking the disassembly code may help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a slicing problem somewhere. Just guessing..

[What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)
no, this is not that case.

You shuld put a try catch block in ~CMain, hmmm one of its member throw an exception in a destructor?

Comment: What do you mean? What is a slicing problem?

Comment: @BastiBechtold: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: If it was a slicing problem then derived class destructors will not be called, isn't it? but here it seems base class destructors are not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't `delete` your object allocated with `new`.

;-)

More seriously, do you have gone into debugging the theoritical end of scope of one of your CList, and step into its destruction process, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

> CMain gets deallocated just fine, but ~CList() is never called.

That sounds like a wrong statement. If `~CMain` is called, then `~CList` is eventually called too, because it's a base class. Check how you detect whether or not a destructor is called.

When you say "CMain gets deallocated", do you mean to say you issue `delete` on it? Check that at the point you do `delete pMain`, the class definition of `CMain` is visible. In absence of its definition, the compiler is allowed to assume the class doesn't have a user defined or virtual destructor, and can omit calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Child, then parent. But in between them, the attributes of the child are destroyed. I would suggest seeing if ~CMain runs to the end - if it does, and ~CList is never entered, you have a problem with one of the attributes of CMain.

Just to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Owned {
    ~Owned() {
        std::cerr << "~Owned" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
};

struct Parent {
    virtual ~Parent() {
        std::cerr << "~Parent" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Owner : public Parent {
    ~Owner() {
        std::cerr << "~Owner" << std::endl;
    }

    Owned owned;
};

int main()
{
    Owner owner;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
~Owner
~Owned
```

And exits with return code 1.